# Dismiss Keyboard React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is there a simple way to hide the iOS keyboard? I want to force it shut in a few specific scenarios that don't necessarily require focusing another view. i.e. like a specific response from the server.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use built-in `Keyboard` Module:

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';

Keyboard.dismiss();
```

Comment: Is there any way to dismiss the keyboard and don't lose the focus?

Answer (score 29):

<s>Was able to achieve this with</s>

```
import dismissKeyboard from 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/dismissKeyboard'
```

And then at the point where I need to toggle the keyboard off

```
dismissKeyboard();
```

-- -- EDIT -- --

Importing like this works equally as well.

```
import dismissKeyboard from 'dismissKeyboard'
```

-- -- EDIT #2 -- --

My original answer is now outdated. The correct way is mentioned below by 
@Chen-Tsu Lin

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';

Keyboard.dismiss();
```

Comment: From React Native 0.35, there is a Keyboard component that you can use. http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/keyboard.html. I couldnt however import {Keyboard} from 'react-native' as documentation suggests. I use const {Keyboard} from 'react-native'.

Comment: I down vote this answer, do not because it's incorrect, just because its outdated. Use Keyboard module buildin in RN

Answer (score 2):

You may also use this library I wrote: [react-native-dismiss-keyboard](https://github.com/DanielMSchmidt/react-native-dismiss-keyboard). It does basically the same as the import of 'dismissKeyboard', but it only uses public API and is therefore safer to use and does not rely on the packager resolving 'dismissKeyboard' as it currently does.

Answer (score 0):

First import Keyboard

```
  import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';
```

Use:

```
Keyboard.dismiss();
```

Comment: So basically the same solution as the one from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39772206/1974224