# How can I close system keyboard in react native

Tags: keyboard, react-native, textinput

I am facing the problem that there seems to be no api for me to close system keyboard. In my code, the component render method looks like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{alert("1111")}}>
    <Text>Alert</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TextInput/>
```

So if I now press the TextInput, the system keyboard will show up as expected. But when I press the Text `Alert` above, I just want to close the system keyboard ( and alert something). But I tried in rn 0.23.1 with win7, the Text `Alert` pressed will not close the system keyboard. What should I do to solve this question?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33560861/2125612

Comment: Great, it works for me, thanks a lot. And I really hold facebook can offer a detailed doc for us...

Answer (score 0):

If you add a ref to the TextInput you can call `blur()` on it in the onPress. Conversely, you can always toggle the keyboard by calling `focus()`.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
  this.refs.Input.blur()
  alert("1111")
}}>
  <Text>Alert</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TextInput ref="Input"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

`import { Keyboard } from 'react-native;`

`<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {Keyboard.dismiss()}}>
  <Text>Alert</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TextInput ref="Input"/>`