# Lose focus and dismiss keyboard on clicking outside of the TextInput field in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have already researched about it and found this post:

[react-native: hide keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685421/react-native-hide-keyboard)

But this didn't work for me. When I touch the portion of the screen thats outside the text input field, I was expecting that the input field will lose focus and the keyboard will get dismissed. But, nothing is happening. The cursor keeps blinking on the input.

Below is the code I tried. Please note that I am using redux-form v6:

```
import dismissKeyboard from 'dismissKeyboard';

<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> dismissKeyboard()}>
        <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
          <Field name="editLocation" component={TextField} />
          <Button onPress={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>Sign In</Button>
        </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

**TextField component** contains TextInput. Not sure if I am doing anything wrong.

I have tested the code on Genymotion emulator with the Samsung S6 image and on my samsung note 4.

Comment: Do you know what the dimensions are of your `TouchableWithoutFeedback` ?

Comment: In other words, do you know if your `onPress` callback is getting called?

Comment: @rclai Perfect. Thanks for commenting your query. Dimension was the real problem. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind, I posted an answer so you can mark it as correct.

Comment: @rclai Sure. No problem.

Comment: use ScrollView. "A better way is to use ScrollView and Keyboard.dismiss. By using ScrollView when the user taps outside of textInput, keyboard dismissed.". This answer has saved my day https://stackoverflow.com/a/43434126/2808371

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the dimensions of your `TouchableWithoutFeedback` to ensure your `onPress` is being called.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer a bit more? How do I check my component's dimensions?

Comment: You can use toggle inspector in the react-native debugger menu or add a backgroundColor to check it