# React-Native: 'onBlur' is not getting fired when touched out side of the TextInput

Tags: react-native, onblur

```
   <TextInput
        ref={ ref => this.mobileNumberRef = ref}
        keyboardType='phone-pad'
        returnKeyType='done'
        onBlur={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
   />
```

I would like to dismiss the keyboard when touched outside of the `TextInput` area. But `onBlur()` is not getting fired.

Can anybody let me know how to achieve this? Thank You!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all `onBlur` called when the text input is blurred. But if you want to dismiss the keyboard when you touched outside of the TextInput area used below scenarios

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
  <TextInput
    onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
    keyboardType="phone-pad"
    returnKeyType="done"
  />
</ScrollView>
```

or

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
    <TextInput
      onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
      keyboardType="phone-pad"
      returnKeyType="done"
    />
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Answer (score 2):

**onBlur** occurs when an Input loses focus.

**Keyboard.Dismiss** Dismisses the active keyboard and removes focus.

By touching outside of the TextInput you will anyway lose focus from the element so I am not sure why do you need `Keyboard.Dimiss` as well.

I've also tested this on the sandbox and for me it works fine. Maybe you can share more code and explain exactly what do you want to achieve?

Lastly please check [Unfocus a TextInput in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431896/unfocus-a-textinput-in-react-native) maybe that will help you solve your issue.