# Keyboard Hiding in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I just followed the answer from the link [react-native: hide keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685421/react-native-hide-keyboard/33560861#33560861)

But the keyboard is coming as flash for fraction of seconds then it is dismissing. Is there is a way to avoid keyboard totally.

Comment: did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685421/react-native-hide-keyboard/39772206#39772206 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide keyboard in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685421/hide-keyboard-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39772206/3950240) helped me:

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native'

// Hide that keyboard!
Keyboard.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct way is to dismiss View with TouchableWithoutFeedback and calling Keyboard.dismiss()

```
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native'

<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
   <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput keyboardType='numeric'/>
   </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Keyboard.dismiss()** for keyboard hide.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Keyboard,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textinput}
          placeholder="Enter Your Name"
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 28,
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  textinput: {
    paddingVertical: 12,
    margin: 8,
    borderRadius: 7,
    backgroundColor: "#F9FBE7",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "#000000",
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});
```