# How to avoid double tap when keyboard is open on Native Base?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, native-base

This is question regarding Native Base framework for React Native applications:

Imagine a subscribe screen; 1 text input and a subscribe button;

After I type my email address I want to tap on subscribe button but my first tap only closes the keyboard and I need to tap again to press on button. How this can be avoided? My expected behaviour is that first tap is a press on button. (As far as I see this is something around < Content > component but I am not sure.)

(I have checked this issue on native-base kitchen sink app and same issue occurs there as well. Just go to: 'Forms and Input' section and see 'Fixed Label' )

Comment: You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685421/react-native-hide-keyboard). The problem is not the same as yours but it might give some idea.

Comment: And also what about using NativeBase's ```Input``` and ```InputGroup``` components instead of RN's ```TextInput```?

Comment: @milkersarac thanks for the comments but I use some custom text inputs and that's why, but the answer I accepted solves the problem.

Comment: Glad it did, great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass this as a prop to the content component.

```
< Content keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works (although I haven't gone through implications yet) thanks a lot! I googled for this quite a lot!

Comment: in my case i needed to add it on the flatlist component

Answer (score 3):

If you use `< Content keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>`, the keypad would not disappear after selecting a button or if you tap outside the input field. To ensure that the keyboard disappears if you tap outside the input field, use

```
< Content keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>
```

However, with this, the keyboard would not disappear if you select a button (as opposed to a blank part of the screen) even though the button's onPress event will get fired. To make the keyboard disappear after pressing a button, the onPress handler of the button should call

```
Keyboard.dismiss()
```

Don't forget to include the import statement:

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';
```

For further details, see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#keyboardshouldpersisttaps

Answer (score 2):

**keyboardShouldPersistTaps** this property is now exist in **ScrollView**.

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
     {..content or component}
</ScrollView>
```

For more detail Please visit on official document

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps