# How to disable keyboard in react native

Tags: react-native

I created a screen keyboard component that I want to disable the platform's keyboard, how I can disable it?

```html
<TextInput
  secureTextEntry
  ref="Pin"
  selectionColor="#656565"
  keyboardType="numeric"
  activeColor="#656565"
  inactiveColor="#fff"
  autoFocus={false}
  ignoreCase
  codeLength={4}
  inputPosition="center"
  size={50}
  onFulfill={isValid => this}
  codeInputStyle={{ borderWidth: 1.5 }}
/>
```

Comment: I think that you could study how it's done here: https://github.com/wix/react-native-keyboard-input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setting `keyboardType` to `null` worked for me

EDIT:

this only worked in the simulator, running it on an actual device the native keyboard still appeared.

wrapping the `<TextInput />` in a `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` element in the example below worked.

`<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} >
    <TextInput />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>`

Answer (score 32):

Just write `showSoftInputOnFocus={false}` in `<TextInput>` like this:

```
<TextInput showSoftInputOnFocus={false} />
```

Answer (score 17):

I had issues also. No other solutions was working for me. This will display text input field and it will be clickable but not editable.

```html
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.openPinKeyboard}>
  <View pointerEvents="none">
    <Input editable={false} value="1234" />
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I can't use the input at all

Comment: That's the point. You can't edit but can click on it.

Comment: He said 'disable keyboard' not 'can't edit it', those things very different

Comment: And exactly - on the press, you can show your custom keyboard. By disabling the input - the native keyboard will not show up and this is the primary goal.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to add something like:

```xml
<TextInput showSoftInputOnFocus={false} keyboardType="numeric" />
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<TextInput showSoftInputOnFocus={false}/>
```

This work for me, sometime I need onFocus action to navigate new screen, and don't need keyboard open animation. Prop Editable will disable textfield, can not pressable

Answer (score 3):

You may try to set `keyboardType` to `none`, if it doesn't work another alternative is to set the `editable` prop to `false`.

Potential answers can be found here : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14045

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to use the onFocus prop on TextInput.

1. Import `Keyboard` from ‘react-native’

> import {Keyboard, TextInput} from
> 'react-native'

2. Then pass `Keyboard.dismiss()` to TextInput onFocus prop, to stop the keyboard from popping up when focused.

> <TextInput onFocus = {()=> Keyboard.dismiss()} .../>

Now test the input field by pressing it to see if the keyboard will pop up

Answer (score 2):

just put this under text input tag this worked for me in react-native

```
              <TextInput
               //this line  
              editable={false}
             />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this solution i hope this will work for android and ios both...

```
// Step 1: Get Keyboard, TouchableWithoutFeedback from ‘react-native’;
        import { View, TextInput, StyleSheet, Keyboard,  TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';

        // Step 2: Create an arrow function to write dismiss keyboard code
        const DismissKeyboard = ({ children }) => (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
                {children}
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            );

        // Step 3: Wrap all TextInput inside <DismissKeyboard> </DismissKeyboard>
        //Example
        <DismissKeyboard>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="email" />
                <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="password" />
            </View>
        </DismissKeyboard>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by pointerEvents="none"

```
<View pointerEvents="none">
           <TextInput
             focusable={false}
             style={{color: '#00000000'}}
             onChangeText={setEmail}
           />
         </View>
```