# I can't dismiss my keyboard in my react native app after an alert

Tags: react-native

I'm currently trying to close the keyboard programmatically:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfY7K.jpg

But it does not work. It actually closes, then reopens when the screen changes, whereas there is no input on the second screen.

I already tried to put `Keyboard.dismiss()` just before changing the screen and in the `componentDidMount()` of the second screen, without success.

Comment: Do you try device or simulator

Comment: I'm running my app under Expo installed on iPhone SE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide keyboard in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685421/hide-keyboard-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens everytime you have an open Alert while trying to hide the Keyboard. It's quite hacky but you can try to wrap your `Alert` in a timeout.

```
setTimeout(() => {
   //... open your alert here
}, 50)
```