# Closing popup on clicking outside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Before wrote this post, I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component), but i'm not able to link all of the code to mine.

This is my toggle component:

```
<ToggleContent
          toggle={show => (
            <div>
              <button type="button" onClick={show} className={styles.acronym}>
                {acronym}
              </button>
            </div>
          )
          }
          content={show => (
            <LogoutCard onClick={show} acronym={acronym} name={name} />
          )}
        />
```

and this is the inside of `ToggleContent`

```
function ToggleContent({ toggle, content }) {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);
  const hide = () => setIsShown(false);
  const show = () => setIsShown(!isShown);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {toggle(show)}
      {isShown && content(hide)}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

and this is the wrapper of LogoutCard inside the props `content`

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

/**
 * Hook that alerts clicks outside of the passed ref
 */
function useOutsideAlerter(ref) {
  /**
   * Alert if clicked on outside of element
   */
  function handleClickOutside(event) {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
      alert("You clicked outside of me!");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // Bind the event listener
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      // Unbind the event listener on clean up
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  });
}

/**
 * Component that alerts if you click outside of it
 */
export default function OutsideAlerter(props) {
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);
  useOutsideAlerter(wrapperRef);

  return <div ref={wrapperRef}>{props.children}</div>;
}
```

***Problem***

The problem is that I'm able to print the alert, but i'm not able to close the popup because I'm not able to pass the `show` value, that's in the only allowed to close and open the little popup.

***Question***

How can I close the popup ?

Comment: It would be good if you can put this in a jsFiddle or codeSandbox or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a say a name, `onClick` function to handle the logic needed to execute to close the popup as needed. Also simplifying the logic to an `toggle` action that just negates the current state would be enough to manage the show / hide behaviour of the popup.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

/**
 * Hook that alerts clicks outside of the passed ref
 */
function useOutsideAlerter(ref, onClick) {
  /**
   * Alert if clicked on outside of element
   */
  function handleClickOutside(event) {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
      alert("You clicked outside of me!");
      onClick();
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // Bind the event listener
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      // Unbind the event listener on clean up
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [handleClickOutside]);
}

/**
 * Component that alerts if you click outside of it
 */
export default function OutsideAlerter(props) {
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

  return <div ref={wrapperRef}>{props.children}</div>;
}

function ToggleContent({ toggle, content }) {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setIsShown(!isShown);

  const onClick = () => {
    toggle()
  }
  useOutsideAlerter(wrapperRef, onClick);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {toggle(show)}
      {isShown && content()}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: just a question that can sound stupid, but consider it's my second month as web dev: i can reach the function ` useOutsideAlerter(wrapperRef, onClick); `

By import only  the component OutsideAlerter ( the wrapper of logoutCard ) ?

Comment: No. Also you should import it where it should be executed. And in your case, the place where it is appropriate is the `ToggleContent` component. `OutsideAlerter` is the function that you render inside `ToggleContent` through the prop `content`.