# RN : Hide keyboard permanently

Tags: android, react-native

There is a build-in function for hide keyboard in react-native call `Keyboard.dismiss()`, but what I wish is the native keyboard will disable during the app running.

**My app no have any TextInput, I using react-native-webview for entire layout

What I have try is add code below to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685421/hide-keyboard-in-react-native

Comment: @ShoaibK. nope, my question have mention i no using any RN build-in TextInput, so those answer doesn't work

Comment: @FeelRightz use "android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" " instead of android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

Comment: @pratikvekariya the keyboard still showing

Comment: @FeelRightz pls check out my answer, hopefully that will work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try with this method....

```
   public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view == null) {
        view = new View(activity);
    }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

put above method in common class like CommonUtils
call method in your activity's onCreate method

```
CommonUtils.hideSoftKeyboard(your_activity.this)
```

Hope this will work for you(this working perfectly for me).

Comment: where is CommonUtils ? i not android native developer, not understand where to put, can you explain how to add into react-native android

Comment: @FeelRightz its just for example, you can add this method in your activity too. Just copy it from here and paste in your activity

Comment: @FeelRightz add this method at end of your activity. before last "}" . 
Check my edited answer, i have added image. if you see red text as per image, click on that text, it will ask for import and do import, your issue will be fix.

Comment: i using visual studio code for develop the app, can you share with me what namespace have been import ?

Comment: @FeelRightz for visual studio i don't know, in android imports are as follows (1).import android.view.View;
(2). import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

Comment: it say error: cannot find symbol , and pointed to Activity

Comment: @FeelRightz for visual studio i dont know exactly which import is correct. I mentioned in above comment is for android studio.