# How to dismiss keyboard and handle Touchable press in single tap - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, mobile, touchableopacity

I have the following simplified React Native code:

```js
<ScreenContainer>
  <View>
    <TextInput
      value={query}
      onChangeText={handleInputChange}
      autoFocus={true}
      onSubmitEditing={() => {}}
    />
  </View>

  <SafeAreaView>
    <FlatList
      data={results.length > 0 ? results : null}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress(item)}>
            // Some other text
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )}
    />
  </SafeAreaView>
</ScreenContainer>
```

The `TextInput` is a search bar that dynamically changes the items in the `Flatlist`. Each item in the `Flatlist` renders a `TouchableOpacity`. Simple enough

Currently, when a search result appears and I tap on the `TouchableOpacity`, it takes 2 presses to register the `handlePress` event: 1 press to dismiss the keyboard and the next to actually handle the press.

Does anyone know how to handle the press and dismiss the keyboard in 1 press? Maybe I should be using a different component or structure my `jsx` differently?

Comment: For dismiss the keyboard.Please check here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34779467/19153194

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [keyboardShouldPersistTaps](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps) property.

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize that `Flatlist` inherits all the props from `ScrollView`. That's what I needed!